# How to sort RecyclerView items by keywords?

Tags: java, android, sorting

I need to sort `RecyclerView` items by keywords. Let's say I have 15 Strings:

- 5 are "music",
- 5 are "movie" ,and
- 5 are "cat"

How can I sort the List so that I can first order the "music" items, then "cat" items, and then "movie" items. For alphabetical and numerical sorting there are `Comparator`s, but I don't know how to sort by keywords.

Just an example of sorting int based valued in descending order:

```
    Collections.sort(markerObjects, new Comparator<MarkerObject>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(MarkerObject o1, MarkerObject o2) {
        return o2.getActive() - (o1.getActive());
      }
    });
```

Comment: have you try using map<String,ArrayList<Any>> map.groupby

Comment: That requires minimal API 25, I am using API 21 but thanks, came across alternative libraries to be used if minimal API is below 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
Collections.sort(shiftingDatumList, new Comparator<ShiftingDatum>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(final ShiftingDatum object1, final ShiftingDatum object2) {
     if (object1.getDestinationSite().getId().equals(Constants.workingSite)) {
             return -1;
     } else if (object2.getDestinationSite().getId().equals(Constants.workingSite)) {
             return 1;
     } else {
             return 0;
     }
```